# How to append a derived class to className - React

Tags: reactjs

I have a class name, which is derived from a prop value, and I want to add it to a predefined class list but I get syntax errors, this is what I'm trying:

```
render() {
    const displayClass = this.props.display ? 'd-block' : 'd-none';
    return (
        <div>
            <div className=`my-class ${displayClass}`>{this.props.message}</div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Is this possible? If so, what's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include curly brackets when using backticks (``):

```
<div className={`my-class ${displayClass}`}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that's it, pretty new to React so a learning curve for me on it's syntax anomalies - will accept when I can